# Fastest possible dictionary-like matching

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, data-structures, spell-checking

I will have to perform a spelling check-like operation in Python as follows:

I have a huge list of words (let's call it the lexicon). I am now given some text (let's call it the sample). I have to search for each sample word in the lexicon. If I cannot find it, that sample word is an error.

In short - a brute-force spelling checker. However, searching through the lexicon linearly for each sample word is bound to be slow. What's a better method to do this?

The complicating factor is that neither the sample nor the lexicon is in English. It is in a language which instead of 26 characters, can have over 300 - stored in Unicode.

A suggestion of any algorithm / data structure / parallelization method will be helpful. Algorithms which have high speed at the cost of less than 100% accuracy would be perfect, since I don't need 100% accuracy. I know about Norvig's algorithm for this, but it seems English-specific.

Comment: You might want to read this article on how to write a spelling corrector, assuming your eventual goal is to find misspelled words, not just correctly spelled ones: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a set of Unicode strings:

```
s = set(u"rabbit", u"lamb", u"calf")
```

and use the `in` operator to check whether a word occurs:

```
>>> u"rabbit" in s
True
>>> u"wolf" in s
False
```

This look-up is essentially O(1), so the size of the dictionary does not matter.

**Edit**: Here's the complete code for a (case-sensitive) spell checker (2.6 or above):

```
from io import open
import re
with open("dictionary", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    words = set(line.strip() for line in f)
with open("document", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for w in re.findall(r"\w+", f.read()):
        if w not in words:
            print "Misspelled:", w.encode("utf-8")
```

(The `print` assumes your terminal uses UTF-8.)

Comment: @Atriya: No, you said in your post that you were using a linear search.  This will use a hash look-up.

Comment: Ah, interesting! O(1) means constant time, whatever be the size of the lexicon? That sounds too good to be true! Thanks, I'll give it a try! Btw, why do people use complex things like 'trie's then?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Isn't O(1) the most optimistic no-hash-collisions case? What about the fact that he wants to index a huge amount of data that could possibly create collisions in the hashing algo? Just a "theoretical" curiosity, though - I don't think that this would change the time for looking up.

Comment: @Atriya: A set only works for *exact* matches.  If you are looking for *prefixes* or *suffixes* of any length, you will need a more complex data structure.

Comment: @luke14free: O(1) is the *amortised* look-up time, that's why I used the word "essentially" in the answer above.  The average look-up time does not depend on the size of the dictionary.

Comment: @luke14free, to be precise, the average look-up depends not on the "size of the dictionary," but on the [load factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_factor_(computer_science)#Load_factor) -- the ratio of stored entries to available slots in the table.

Comment: The load factor of Python dictionaries defaults to 2/3, which means you are usually wasting 1/3 of the memory. Also note that creating a dictionary is not O(1) since you have to re-hash (grow) it every time it's filled over the load factor. For large dictionaries or possibly higher performance you may consider using a Trie as in Marcins answer.

Comment: @EmilVikström: Creating a dictionary (or a set, in this context) with n entries is of course at least O(n), not O(1).  And since the capacity is doubled once the *maximum* load factor is reached, creating a set is amortised O(n) -- there's no advantage to a trie in this regard.

Comment: @senderle Just to be correct: It depends on the load factor assuming a perfect hash function with uniform distribution, otherwise all bets are off.  Also: Afaik python doesn't double the size, but instead goes for a lower increase - still amortized O(1) insert, but usually less wasted memory.

Comment: @Voo: Python doesn't double the size of lists, but does so for sets and dictionaries.  (Of course I'm talking about the CPython implementation.)

Comment: @Sven That's interesting. Was there any particular reason for using two different growth strategies? I'd think the arguments that apply for the reason of a factor lower than 2 for lists would apply to sets and dicts as well.

Comment: @Voo: There are at least two reasons.  1) Growing a list is much cheaper than growing a dicionary, so a higher growth factor might be expedient. 2) The hashes must be reduced modulo the size of the dict/set.  For powers of 2, this can be done without a division. (The strategy the dict uses is different from a simple modulo, but the argument in principle holds.)

Comment: @Sven Right, what was I thinking. CS 101: Either use primes for your hashtables or powers of 2. Thanks *goes into a dark corner*

Answer (score 1):

This is where [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) come in place. Create a set of all the words in your dictionary and then use a membership operator to check if the word is present in the dictionary or not.

Here is a simplified example

```
>>> dictionary = {'Python','check-like', 'will', 'perform','follows:', 'spelling', 'operation'}
>>> for word in "I will have to perform a spelling check-like operation in Python as follows:".split():
    if word in dictionary:
        print "Found {0} in the dictionary".format(word)
    else:
        print "{0} not present in the dictionary".format(word)


I not present in the dictionary
Found will in the dictionary
have not present in the dictionary
to not present in the dictionary
Found perform in the dictionary
a not present in the dictionary
Found spelling in the dictionary
Found check-like in the dictionary
Found operation in the dictionary
in not present in the dictionary
Found Python in the dictionary
as not present in the dictionary
Found follows: in the dictionary
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a tree structure to store the words, such that each path from root to leaf represents a single word. If your traversal cannot reach a leaf, or reaches a leaf before the end of the word, you have a word not in your lexicon.

Apart from the benefits Emil mentions in the comments, note also that this allows you to do things like back-tracking to find alternative spellings.

Comment: This is also called a Trie or Prefix tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie To check if a word is in the dictionary is on the order of O(n) of the word length, which should be impossible to outpeform. Hashmaps should have the same complexity, but usually with larger constant factors. Therefore this is a really good datastructure for the problem!

Comment: @EmilVikström It also has better memory performance, and potentially allows one to derive more information (depending on what the programme is doing).

Comment: @EmilVikström: The comment about the constant is wrong in the context of Python.  The highly optimised built-in set and dict data structures will easily outperform any Python-implementation of a trie by quite a margin.

Comment: @SvenMarnach It depends on whether or not the programme is going to treat words as atomic. If there is a desire to do anything like work out if there a missing space between two words, an algorithm working with a prefix tree is going to be much more efficient. It is only for simple lookup where the dictionary wins out. Also, if the lexicon is really enormous, space performance is going to matter.

Comment: @atriya should try the simple solution (a set) first. If it's really too slow, *then* he can consider alternatives. A prefix tree *might* be a a good choice, but do you need it? I say it *might* because linguistic text is redundant, and a trie will be sub-optimally deep-- there must be a reason python uses hashmaps and not tries for its lookups!

Comment: @alexis Yes, that reason is that hashmaps are intended for atomic keys. A trie will not be faster for lookups of single atoms. It is likely that if this programme suffers any feature-creep whatsoever, it will be faster (and quite possibly vastly easier) to use a prefix tree.

Comment: I have done much better in python with hand rolled ternary trees or actual tries, when the number of strings grows large.  I don't understand the advice to assume something is optimal without profiling, or the "there must be a reason" handwaving.  If you are optimising, profile your options and analyse the data structures and algorithmic complexity.  It's about being professional.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll start with sets and then move to prefix trees or tries if required.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a set, like everyone is telling you. Set lookups were optimized in python's C code by experienced programmers, so there's no way you can do better in your little application.

Unicode is not an issue: Set and dictionary keys can be unicode or English text, it doesn't matter. The only consideration for you might be unicode normalization, since different orders of diacritics would not compare equal. If this is an issue for your language, I would first ensure the lexicon is stored in normalized form, and then normalize each word before you check it. E.g., `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', word)`

Comment: Just because something is optimised c code doesn't mean it cannot be done better.  The most obvious reason is due to use of wrong data structure or algorithm, and this is a great example here.  It is rarely optimal to use a dictionary data structure (some tree - often red, black - with a full string on each node to compare with).  That is an O(N) compare on each node, with O(ln(M)) depth!.  I have done much better in python with hand rolled ternary trees or actual tries, when the number of strings grows large.

Comment: No argument there. Perhaps python's designers really made a mistake, or perhaps hashes are the best all-round solution but are not optimal for this domain. However, @atriya is more or less a beginner (no offense), so I doubt he is likely to do much better than set lookups. Hence my advice.

Comment: Thanks. No offense taken, but I MUST find the most efficient way to do it. I'll start with sets, but I may have to move to these rolled ternary trees and tries later.

Answer (score 0):

The average time complexity of hashed search in a python dictionary is O(1). You can therefore use a "dictionary with no values" (a.k.a. a set)

Answer (score 0):

That's what python dictionaries and sets are for! :)
Either store your lexicon in a dictionary if each word has some value (say frequency), or a set if you just need to check for existence. Searching them is O(1) so it will be damn fast.

```
lex = set(('word1', 'word2', .....))

for w in words:
    if w not in lex:
        print "Error: %s" % w
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to create index of your lexicon. for example you can make your own indexing system, but better way is using of full-text search engines  [Full text search engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search)
I may recomend apache lucene or sphinx for you. it's both fast and open source.
After you may send a searche queries from python to search engine and catch replies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post I wrote on checking such things. It's simular to have the google suggestion/spell checker works.

http://blog.mattalcock.com/2012/12/5/python-spell-checker/

Hope it helps.